# How to Disable Windows 10 update permanently?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

How to permanently disable all notifications and updates to Windows 10?
Currently when I open Windows Update panel the first main update is Upgrade to Windows 10 system.
Other updates are not installed.
Thank-you

Comment: Try clicking on taskbar icons and select customization this opens the control panel at 'Notification Area Icons' or go straight to by way of control panel. Click on GWX[get windows 10] and select 'Hide notifications and icons '

Comment: What do you mean "other updates are not installed" exactly?

Answer (score 6):

This guide helps you to completely remove the Windows 10 upgrade notifications and clean up.

## Disable Autostart of GWX.exe:

[image: img1]

Under "Autostart Location" you can find the Autostart path of gwx.exe. Without a uninstallation of the KB3035583 update gwx.exe can only be disabled temporary. It gets reactivated after reboot. To solve this read the following:

## Uninstall KB3035583:

- Press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Insert appwiz.cpl
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Click `Installed Updates` in the sidebar
- Right-Click on `Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3035583)`
- Uninstall
- **Important:** Directly confirm the `restart prompt`!

**Source:**
[What is the “Get Windows 10″ Tray Item and How Do You Remove It?](http://www.howtogeek.com/218856/how-do-you-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-tray/)

Comment: This answer would be much better if you'd [edit] to include the content from that link

Comment: @CanadianLuke I added additional information